# htaccess: how to redirect every url that starts with http://example.com/shop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Like the title says, how do I redirect every url that starts with http://example.com/shop to a single page?

so I have:

- http://example.com/shop/index
- http://example.com/shop/detail/52
- http://example.com/shop/download

.... etc, and it should be redirected to http://example.com/new_page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [mod_alias’ `RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectMatch ^/shop(/|$) /new_page
```

Or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^shop(/|$) /new_page [R]
```

Note the different pattern for `RewriteRule` as mod_rewrite removes the contextual path prefix in [per-directory rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) before testing the rules.

Comment: mod_alias is different from mod_rewrite i guess? and what does the [R] mean?

Comment: @krike: Yes. With the directives of mod_alias you can only process the URI path; with mod_rewrite you can also test other parts of the request like the query or header fields. The `[R]` is to force an external redirect; otherwise the request would only be rewritten internally.

Comment: ok thanks :) will try that as soon as I finished the new version of my website :)